# How to debug pymongo ServerSelectionTimeoutError on remote server?

Tags: pymongo, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I'm getting:
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: test.net:10255: timed out

I've set already set ssl=true and ssl_cert_reqs=CERT_NONE in the string I'm passing to the MongoDB client, as recommended by past answers.

Any ideas?